# Registrar las asistencias (Entrada y Salida) de un empleado ya registrado - PHP & MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy trancado con un sistema que estoy haciendo para la universidad, y necesito saber cómo puedo hacer que mi sistema, el cual ya registra empleados de una institución me registre las asistencias de entrada y salida.

Ya tengo programado un sistema de *CRUD* para los empleados.

Tengo en mi base de datos dos tablas: `trabajadores` y `asistencias`, lo cual está implementado de la siguiente manera.

```
trabajadores(id, cedula, nombres, apellidos, correo, telefono)
```

```
asistencias(id, fecha, hora_entrada, hora_salida, observacion, id_trabajador)
```

¿Cómo puedo registrar las asistencias de determinado trabajador alojado en la tabla foránea de asistencias?

---

Necesito saber **cómo puedo registrar una asistencia**, lo cual ya tengo entendido de meter los datos en la tabla mediante PHP & MYSQL, lo que se me complica, es tomar mi clave foránea y hacer que esa asistencia se me registre del id de ese trabajador.

Ya he registrado en mi tabla trabajador:

```
id = 1
cedula = 1068844
nombre = Ernesto
apellido = Suares
telefono = 83823
correo = ernesto@gmail.com
```

y quiero que en asistencia se registre de esta manera

```
id = 1
fecha = 10/10/2016
hora_entrada: 10:00
hora_salida: 12:00
observacion = Asistió
trabajador_id = 1
```

Y ahora mi siguiente registro de asistencia:

```
id = 2
fecha = 11/10/2016
hora_entrada = 10:30
hora_salida = 12:00
observacion = Asistió
```

Quiero hacerle otro registro a `"Ernesto Suarez"` me agarre de nuevo el `id 1`.

Osea, solo quiero que al yo crear una nueva asistencia con un formulario que tengo, se me registre la asistencia del trabajador ya registrado en mi base de datos. Solo quiero que se me registre mi dato foráneo del trabajador.

Comment: Por favor aclara en cuanto a con que tienes inconveniente, pues mencionas que ya tienes el CRUD de empleados, entonces supongo que sabes hacer una conexión a base de datos desde PHP. ¿te refieres a las sentencias SQL que debes usar? ¿te refieres a que funciones usar en PHP? ¿tu problema es  con la estructura? ¿tienes problema con la lógica de tu aplicación?

Comment: Así es, necesito saber como puedo registrar una asistencia, lo cual ya tengo entendido de meter los datos en la tabla mediante PHP & MYSQL, lo que se me complica, es tomar mi clave foranea la cual es "trabajador_id" y hacer que esa asistencia se me registre del id de ese trabajador.. si tengo por ejemplo en mi primer campo registrado a "Ernesto Suarez" el cual es el id 1 y quiero hacer un registro de asistencia, y si quiero hacerle otro registro a "Ernesto Suarez" me agarre de nuevo el id 1.

Comment: Bueno de lo poco que puedo entender creo que el problema es de lógica, dado que si `asistencias.id_trabajador` es una llave foránea referencia de `trabajadores.id` esto implicaría que para guardar el registro en `asistencias` primero debe existir el trabajador, por tanto no entendería cual es el problema en el registro. A menos que intentes guardar primero en `asistencia` sin haber registrado el `trabajador`

Comment: Ya he registrado en mi tabla trabajador:
id = 1
cedula = 1068844
nombre = Ernesto
apellido = Suares
telefono = 83823
correo = ernesto@gmail.com

y quiero que en asistencia se registre de esta manera
id = 1
fecha = 10/10/2016
hora_entrada: 10:00
hora_salida: 12:00
observacion = Asistió
trabajador_id = 1

Comment: Y ahora mi siguiente registro de asistencia:
id = 2
fecha = 11/10/2016
hora_entrada = 10:30
hora_salida = 12:00
observacion = Asistió pero entró media hora tarde
trabajador_id = 1

Comment: Estuve tratando de crear un chat, pero no encontré la manera. El punto es ¿Que te impide hacerlo?

Comment: Osea, solo quiero que al yo crear una nueva asistencia con un formulario que tengo, se me registre la asistencia del trabajador ya registrado en mi base de datos. Solo quiero que se me registre mi dato foranero del trabajador.

Comment: He planteado una solución basándome en la apreciación que tengo de este problema, por favor intenta editar tu pregunta, mejora la redacción y suma detalles, ademas podrías compartir un poco de código para que le sea útil para otros usuarios que encuentren un dilema parecido.

Comment: Una sugerencia, ¿ por qué separas la hora y la fecha en 2 campos ? Es mejor que tener sólo dos campos DateTime uno para entrada y otro para salida, por que de la forma en que lo estas haciendo ¿ Cómo registrarias un empleado que entra el **30-06-2017 22:00:00 y sale el 01-07-2017 01:30:00**, por ejemplo?

Answer (score 2):

Basándome en los comentarios a tu pregunta trataré de guiarte un poco, supongo a que te refieres que tienes un formulario algo así:

```html
<form action="..." id="formulario_asistencia">
    <input type="number" name="id">
    <input type="date" name="fecha">
    <input type="time" name="hora_entrada">
    <input type="time" name="hora_salida">
    <input type="text" name="observacion">
    <input type="number" name="cedula_trabajador">
    <button type="submit">Guardar</button>
</form>
```

Cuando enviás el formulario obviamente recibes la cédula del trabajador mas no su id, y lo que tienes referenciado como llave foránea es el id, por tanto deberás primero realizar una consulta previa así:

```
$cedula = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'cedula_trabajador'); /* Suponiendo que el método de envió fue POST */
$sql = "SELECT id FROM cedula = '$cedula'";
/* Aquí van las funciones que usas para hacer consultas SQL desde PHP
/* Asumamos que de estas operaciones obtuviste un arreglo $respuesta */
```

Notaras que el propósito es capturar el id correspondiente a la cédula, para luego usarlo en una consulta previa:

```
$id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'id');
$fecha = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'fecha');
$hora_entrada = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'hora_entrada');
$hora_salida = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'hora_salida');
$observacion = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'observacion');

$id_trabajador = $respuesta['id'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO asistencias(id, fecha, hora_entrada, hora_salida, observacion, id_trabajador) 
    VALUES ('$id', '$fecha', '$hora_entrada', '$hora_salida', '$observacion', '$id_trabajador');"
/* Aquí van las funciones que usas para hacer consultas SQL desde PHP */
```

**Precaución:** *para tener en cuenta que no estoy definiendo ningún método de protección contra ataques SQL a modo de ser ilustrativo, pero es claro que los métodos que implemente para hacer las consultas SQL deber realizar los correspondientes filtros y en los posible preparar las consultas.*